# Mongoose find in array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
    streamer: {
        streamer_username: String,
        streams: [{
            id: String,
            messages: [{
                date: String,
                username: String,
                message: String,
                song: String
            }]
        }]
    }
})
```

It contains an array "streams", which contains objects that have the "id" value, as you can see. I'm trying to search the DB with this query.

`MsgSchema.find({ "streamer.streamer_username" : streamer_name, "streamer.streams": { "$in": {id: response.data[0].id} }}, (err, found) =>{}})`

But i find nothing. Even if i remove the first "username" part, it still doesn't find anything and returns an empty array, so the problem is clearly the second part.
What is wrong with my query? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: Read the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: `MsgSchema.find({ "streamer.streamer_username" : streamer_name, "streamer.streams.id": {"$in": response.data[0].id}}, (err, found) =>{}})`
Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I am late but I hope it helps other people

You can simply use `.find()` and inside it, you can create the specifications of the conditions on more than one field nested in an array of documents. The easiest way is:

```
MessageSchema.find({ "streamer.streams": { id: "XXX" } });
```